# coffee machine problem probability with normal distribution

Tags: probability

I have the following question homework. One coffee machine fills one product with $\mathcal{N}(\mu, 10^2)$ distributuion. How much should be regulated the average weight $\mu$ so that only 10% of the packages are less than 500g?

I tried some attempt but I can't finalize the solution. First, I think that the question is equivalente to find $\mu$ so that the following equation

$$\hbox{Pr}(X<500) = 0.1$$

And using $X = \sigma Z + \mu$, we have

$$\hbox{Pr}(Z< \frac{(500 - \mu)}{\sigma} ) = 0.1$$

So, I think that there is no way  to use the Z distribution table. Some ideias?

Comment: $\Pr(Z\lt -k)=0.1$ if and only if $\Pr(Z\gt k)=0.1$.

Comment: You could use that $ \Phi (z) + \Phi (-z) = 1 $ for all $ z \in \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Pr(X < 500) = \Pr(Z < \frac{500 - \mu}{10}) = .1 = \phi(\frac{500 - \mu}{10}) = \phi(-1.281551)$

$\frac{500 - \mu}{10} = -1.281551 \implies \mu = 512.816$